# Parent NoArgument Contructor invoking overridden method

Tags: java, default, subclass

ot sure if a similar question do exists or have been answered earlier. I did a search but couldn't find anything related.

Please see following example. There's a class A with noargument contructor. Class B extends Class A but no default contructor exists. The output is B-> get c, and I think java uses the runtime polymorphism logic to invoke the B object method.

Here would like to understand if its correct and how Java works here (Maybe what's the underlying logic)

Thanks

```
public class A {

    private String cStr="";
    private String dStr="";

    A()
    {
        getcStr();
    }

    public String getcStr() {
        System.out.println("A-> get c");
        return cStr;
    }

    public String getdStr() {
        System.out.println("A-> get d");
        getcStr();
        return dStr;
    }
}
public class B extends A{

    private String cStr;

    public String getcStr() {
        System.out.println("B-> get c");
        return cStr;
    }
}
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    A a= new B();
    a.getdStr();
}
```

EDIT: the output for the a.getdStr() is A-> get d B-> get c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no default constructor for B so it'll call A() constructor.....

Now `new B();` creates the object of B so java will first look into class B that is any procedure like `getcstr()` exists if procedure found there it will invoke it otherwise check in the super class for that procedure......

Comment: I think this is more to what I am looking, yes I had read that the method resolution process is it will look for a method in its class so this doesn't matter even if a superclass method is invoked?

Comment: where can I get more information regarding this method lookup process of java thanks

Answer (score 3):

If a class doesn't have a default constructor, in your case `B`, then java will implicitly insert a no argument constructor something like this

```
public B() {
   super();
}
```

To answer your question, Yes, due to run time polymorphism, Java invoke's `B`'s  `getcStr()` method. Because B's constructor is calling A's constructor via super()

This is a famous anti-pattern. And its anti-pattern because you are trying to invoke a overriden method on `B` before `B` is fully constructed

Imagine your `B` class was like this

```
public class B extends A{

    private String cStr = "abc";



    public String getcStr() {
        System.out.println(cStr);
        return cStr;
    }
}
```

Now the output of your program would have been `null` instead of `"abc"` because `B` is not fully constructed yet (that means `cStr` is not initialized to `"abc"`)

Comment: Thanks for the response, got your point. was aware of the implicit no argument constructor as you mentioned the cstr value is printing null